# How to call method from one class in another class

Tags: c#

I am new to c# coding.
I have two classes: `frmItem` and `commonFun`

`commonFun` contains a method like this:

```
public static int convertint(string value)
{
    int pass = 0;
    try
    {
        if (value != "") Convert.ToInt32(value);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return pass;                     
}
```

I want call this method to frmItem class.

Comment: Well, you'd call `commonFun.convertint(someArgument)` - but I'd *strongly* advise you to get a good book as an introduction to C#. That will cover questions like this and a lot more. Stack Overflow is a great site for specific questions, but it's *not* a good way to learn a language from scratch. As an aside, now would also be a good time to learn .NET naming conventions, before you get into bad habits.

Comment: thank you...can you provide good book name to me.

Comment: C# in a Nutshell, Head-First C#, Essential C#...

Answer (score 0):

You can call it by:

```
int intReturn = commonFun.convertint(yourStringHere);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

What you forgot in your `convertint` method, is to convert the value with a variable to set its value. change your code to this one:

```
public static int convertint(string value)
{
    int pass = 0;
    try
    {
         if (value != "")
         {  
      /* --> */  pass = Convert.ToInt32(value);
         }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return pass;                     
}
```

Then, make sure the `commonFun` class is public
And after that, in `commonFun` code:

```
string textToConvert= //something
int convertedInt = frmItem.convertint(textToConvert);
```

Hope it helped!

By the way, why don't you just use the `Convert.ToInt32()` Method inside your code? because for me the `convertint` method looks quiet unnecessary.